# 1С УТ 11.3 изменения в обмене с сайтом

Tags: 1с

Добрый день

Есть 1С и настроенный обмен с сайтом по CommerceML.
При обмене с УТ 11.2 всё хорошо, но при обмене с УТ 11.3 заказы в 1С не импортируются.

Вопрос: подскажите что поменялось в модуле обмена в УТ 11.3 и в каком виде теперь надо выгружать заказы?

пример экспортного файла с заказом https://cloud.mail.ru/public/B8w3/W1eaWuPJ9

Comment: Не импортируются... какая ошибка?

Comment: Явной ошибки не выдаёт, в журнале регистрации есть запись о том, что в результате обмена создан заказ клиента, но в списке заказов клиентов он не появляется.

Comment: я так понял, что лицензии нет?

Comment: Поддержка 1С бесполезна, всё что они могут это порекомендовать битрикс.
А у нас своя система и нам надо отладить обмен.

Comment: Честно, тут надо смотреть код. Запускать отладчик и смотреть. По поводу поддержки 1С, то я даже сохранял переписки, чтобы поржать.